# What does shared file transfer speed depends on?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, file-sharing

I have discovered that I can transfer shared files from my PC to my Android phone.I am using ES File Explorer, and I was wondering what the transfer speed depends on?

For example, if I start transferring a large file, will that affect my Internet (download/upload) speed on my PC?
My download speed is 2.7 Mbps , and my upload speed is 250 Kbps.

I have tried searching the web for an answer, but with no luck.

If I knew how I'm transferring files, I wouldn't be asking this question:) In ES File explorer, I got to LAN -> MY PC and from there I transfer shared file. It's wireless transfer but my question is if it affect download/upload speeds.

Comment: If i knew how i'm transferring files, i wouldn't be asking this question:) In es File explorer, i got to LAN -> MY PC and from there i transfer shared file. it's wireless transfer but my question is if it affect download/upload speeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're transferring the files over your local wireless network in your house (probably PC -> cable -> router -> Wi-Fi -> phone), so it is going over the same network as your internet traffic. But like most people, your internet connection is slower than your local network (your Wi-Fi) so these transfers shouldn't affect it - there's plenty of room for both to fit through the Wi-Fi at the same time.

Comment: My transfer speed is 1.5 MBPS , and yes this is what i was looking for, thanks!